# Amazon S3 Change S3Canned ACL Of Existing Files (C#)

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, sdk

I upload a file to a S3 bucket with a public accessibility using the c# sdk:

```
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(this.S3Client);
var fileTransferUtilityRequest = new TransferUtilityUploadRequest
{
    BucketName = bucketName,
    Key = key,
    InputStream = stream,
    StorageClass = S3StorageClass.Standard,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.PublicRead,
};
var response = await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync(fileTransferUtilityRequest);
```

I want to allow the user to go back and forth between the file being public or private.
So I need to change this existing file to CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private.

There is a way to do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing a found a simple solution:

```
var updateObjectRequest = new PutACLRequest
{
    BucketName = ...,
    Key = ...,
    CannedACL = S3CannedACL.Private,
};

var response = await this.S3Client.PutACLAsync(updateObjectRequest);
```